# Time complexity analysis

Tags: java, performance, time-complexity

Sorry, I don't have the time to write a long contextual spiel here. This is a question from a practice exam I'm doing at the moment, and all my University resources are offline (great Uni, I know). I'm completely stumped on how to even start this. Could someone walk me through it? I'm not the greatest with math.

Consider the following recursive method:

```
public static int triple(int x) {
    if (x == 0) return 0;
    else return add(3, triple(decrement(x)));
}
```

Assuming that the worst case time performance for the decrement method is constant
and that the add method is linear in its second parameter (i.e., the time for add(x,y)
can be expressed as `by+a` for some constants `b` and `a`), derive the smallest `big O` that
describes the worst case time performance of the triple method in terms of x.
To derive a complexity for this method, determine and expand recurrence relations for
the first several method instances (problem sizes) and then generalise your expressions
to form a closed form equation for the `nth case`. Show your workings.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time to write a long, detailed answer here.

Comment: 700+ rep and you're still asking us to do your homework?

Comment: There is a [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) and obviously you haven't read it.

Comment: [SO is not tied to your deadline.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135880/183887) More precisely, you being on a deadline doesn't exempt you from the normal guidelines here - let alone the decency not to cuss at people.

Comment: Don't take the question down. I'm working on an outline for you. There may be others.

Comment: If the website of your university that contains important stuff is down the night before the exam complain to whoever's responsible for it tomorrow. However, no matter how stressed you are - don't start cussing around here ("get off my ass"). Comments cleaned up, let's be nice from now on.

Comment: Complaining to the University at 2am is obviously going to fall on deaf ears. "Get off my ass" is probably the most polite cuss to ever qualify for the title.

Answer (score 2):

For a specific x, `triple` will be called recursively with 0, 1, 2, ... x. Let's call these arguments in recursive calls `i`. When the argument is `i`, `add`'s second arg is `3(i-1)`. That means that the cost of such an `add` call is linear in `i`. So each recursive call is linear in the argument to `triple`. There are `x` such calls, so you've got the sum of an arithmetic series (0 + 3 + 6 + ...) -- and that's O(n<sup>2</sup>) time complexity.

You can play with this code:

```
public class Test
{
  static int time;
  public static int triple(int x) {
    if (x == 0) return 0;
    else return add(3, triple(decrement(x)));
  }
  private static int add(int i, int j) {
    System.out.println("Spending " + j);
    time += j;
    return i + j;
  }
  private static int decrement(int x) { time++; return x-1; }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i+=10) {
      time = 0;
      System.out.format("triple(%d)=%d; time=%d\n", i, triple(i), time);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Form a table mapping the value of x to the number of times the triple method executes. Then form a relationship between the two.

```
x |  executions |              Executions
-------------------------------------
0  | T(0)                     |  0 A(0)
1  | T(1) + A(3,1) + T(0)     |  3 A(1)
2  | T(2) + + A(3,1) + T(1)   |  6 A(2)
3  | T(3) + A(3,1)            |  9 A(3)

   Time Complexity for T= T(n)+T(n-1)+...+T(n-n)
   Number of add calls is linear O(n)   

   nth term for number of executions
   Un = 3+(n-1)d
      = 3+(n-1)3

   the sum of the an arithmetic series making it O(n^2)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that for each execution you need to determine the value of the second arg to add (which is the result of the next `triple` call).

Answer (score 1):

First, figure out how often triple is called recursively for a given x. Make a table like the one suggested above. This will give you part of the generalized term.

Second, for every execution of triple, what is the worst case time complexity you can have? Hint, that's determined by the add() function.

Then generalize.

Comment: Thanks a lot, at least this is a starting point!

Comment: BTW, I'm pretty sure that x must be a greater or equal to 0. for negative numbers you get into trouble.

Comment: Yeah I agree, as you can see by the fact that its website fell down the night before the final exam, my University's Computer Science division isn't the sharpest set of tools in the set

Comment: Okay, I got the time complexity as O(n) where n is the value of x originally put into triple. Sound right? :/

Comment: And yeah, I think you're right.

Comment: Because T(n) is evaluates to T(n-1) + T(n-2)...T(n-n)
And for any "T", the time complexity is determined by the complexity of "A" (add), which is O(n) so I guess that makes it O(n*n).

Comment: Working on the answer...

Comment: O(n^2) sounds right to me. add() only adds a linear constant, so you drop this. Figuring out how to write this down nicely is a bit of a pain, though.

Comment: Actually, time spent in `add` is the key.

Answer (score 1):

Okay the way I ended up deriving it (and thanks for all the nice people posting answers to get me going) was to take Jochen's advice and work out a quick complexity map, which made everything a lot simpler.

First, note that the question stipulates that add is O(n) time.

Next, a basic "Triple" call hierarchy:

```
n  |  Time complexity:
------------------------------------------
1  | T(1) + (T(0) = 1   )
2  | T(2) + (T(1) = ... )
3  | T(3) + (T(2) = ... )
```

obviously a pattern is emerging...

```
n  | Time complexity
-------------------------------------------
n  | T(n) + T(n - 1)
```

So it appears that T(n)'s time complexity is `n * T` where `T` is the time complexity for a triple call. Given that the source of growth for the call is from `add` and `add`'s time complexity is `O(n)`, the time complexity becomes `n * n` or `O(n^2)`

Thanks guys, let me know if I used the wrong terminology or something.

EDIT: Some of the addition was off, still same BigO notation though.

Comment: Nicely done. Not much to add to this.